# Re-submit a sitemap to Google Webmaster tools via command line?

Tags: google-search-console, api

I'm on Windows 8.1, trying to resubmit an existing sitemap to Google Webmaster tools via the commandline.

I've read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/quickstart/quickstart-oacurl) but I can't get it to work.

I've followed the instructions for authorising OACurl etc - I'm using the Cygwin terminal for windows.

I'm able to run commands such as

```
java -cp oacurl-1.3.0.jar com.google.oacurl.Fetch "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites"
```

Which gives me a result like so

```
{
 "siteEntry": [
  {
   "siteUrl": "http://catamac.com.au/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteOwner"
  },
  {
   "siteUrl": "http://www.catamac.com.au/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteOwner"
  },
  {
   "siteUrl": "http://www.onlinestore.catamac.com.au/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteOwner"
  },
  {
   "siteUrl": "http://onlinestore.catamac.com.au/",
   "permissionLevel": "siteOwner"
  }
 ]
}
```

I can't see any documentation however, on submitting sitemaps using OACurl?

I'd really like to be able to perform this operation using CURL from the Windows Command Line, using code from [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sitemaps/submit) except I get the following error message when I try and run this command: (obviously replacing my API key)

```
curl PUT https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onlinestore.catamac.com.au%2F/sitemaps/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onlinestore.catamac.com.au%2Fsitemap-engineparts.txt?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Error message:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: PUT; Host not found
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: If the sitemap exists and Google has been reading it just fine, then there is nothing for you to do. Google will discover your updated sitemap fairly quickly. It is advisable not to try and hurry Google up. It does not work. Cheers!!

Comment: Looks like you are not making use of this properly, or supply correct value to  --consumer-key=YOUR_CLIENT_ID --consumer-secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET

Comment: @closetnoc It is an existing sitemap but we are constantly adding to it!

Comment: That is fine. If you leave it alone, it will get noticed and read. You do not need to ping Google.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate that you don't need an answer any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have superseded my need to submit this sitemap to Google. Another user helpfully pointed out that Google will notice the additions to my sitemap, without me having to re-submit it. Thanks!